# String searching in text file and dict values combinations

Tags: python, file, dictionary

i'm a total beginner to python, i'm studying it at university and professor gave us some work to do before the exam. Currently it's been almost 2 weeks that i'm stuck with this program, the rule is that we can't use any library.
Basically I have this dictionary with several possibility of translations from ancient language to english, a dictionary from english to italian (only 1 key - 1 value pairs), a text file in an ancient language and another text file in Italian. Until now what i've done is basically scan the ancient language file and search for corresponding strings with dictionary (using .strip(".,:;?!") method), now i saved those corresponding strigs that contain at least 2 words in a list of strings.
Now comes the hard part: basically i need to try all possible combination of translations (values from ancient language to English) and then take these translations from english to italian the the other dictionary and check if that string exists in the Italian file, if yes i save the result and the paragraph where has been found (result in different paragraphs doesn't count, must be in the same I've made a small piece of code to count the paragraphs).
I'm having issues here for the following reasons:

1. In the strings that i've found how I'm supposed to replace the words and keep the punctuation? Because the return result must contain all the punctuation otherwise the output result will be wrong
2. If the string is contained but in 2 different lines of the text how should i proceed in order to make it work? For example i have a string of 5 words, at the end of a line i found the first 2 words corresponding but the remaining 3 words are the first 3 words of the next line.
3. As mentioned before the dict from ancient language to english is huge and can have up to 7 values (translations) for each key (ancient langauge), is there any efficient way to try all the combinations while searching if the string exists in a text file? This is probably the hardest part.
   Probably the best way to process this is word by word scan every time and in case the sequence is broken i reset it somehow and keep scanning the text file...
   Any idea?

Here you have commented code of what i've managed to do until now:

```
k = 2       #Random value, the whole program gonna be a function and the "k" value will be different each time

file = [ line.strip().split(';') for line in open('lexicon-GR-EN.csv', encoding="utf8").readlines() ]       #Opening CSV file with possible translations from ancient Greek to English
gr_en = { words[0]: tuple(words[1:]) for words in file }                                                    #Creating a dictionary with the several translations (values)    



file = open('lexicon-EN-IT.csv', encoding="utf8")     # Opening 2nd CSV file
en_it = {}                                            # Initializing dictionary
for row in file:                                      # Scanning each row of the CSV file (From English to Italian)
    L = row.rstrip("\n").split(';')                   # Clearing newline char and splitting the words
    x = L[0]
    t1 = L[1]
    en_it[x] = t1                                     # Since in this CSV file all the words are 1 - 1 is not necesary any check for the length (len(L) is always 2 basically)
                              
    
file = open('odyssey.txt', encoding="utf8")           # Opening text file
result = ()                                           # Empty tuple
spacechecker = 0                                      # This is the variable that i need to determine if i'm on a even or odd line, if odd the line will be scanned normaly otherwise word order and words will be reversed
wordcount = 0                                         # Counter of how many words have been found  
paragraph = 0                                         # Paragraph counter, starts at 0
paragraphspace = 0                                    # Another paragraph variable, i need this to prevent double-space to count as paragraph  
string = ""                                           # Empty string to store corresponding sequences 
foundwords = []                                       # Empty list to store words that have been found 
completed_sequences = []                              # Empty list, here will be stored all completed sequences of words      
completed_paragraphs = []                             # Paragraph counter, this shows in which paragraph has been found each sequence of completed_sequences

for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):       # Starting line by line scan of the txt file  
        words = line.split()                          # Splitting words
        if not line.isspace() and index == 0:         # Since i don't know nothing about the "secret tests" that will be conducted with this program i've set this check for the start of the first paragraph to prevent errors: if first line is not space  
            paragraph += 1                            # Add +1 to paragraph counter  
            spacechecker += 1                         # Add +1 to spacechecker
            
        elif not line.isspace() and paragraphspace == 1:     # Checking if the previous line was space and the current is not                   
            paragraphspace = 0                               # Resetting paragraphspace (precedent line was space) value  
            spacechecker += 1                                # Increasing the spacechecker +1
            paragraph +=1                                    # This means we're on a new paragraph so +1 to paragraph
            
        elif line.isspace() and paragraphspace == 1:         # Checking if the current line is space and the precedent line was space too.
            continue                                         # Do nothing and cycle again
            
        elif line.isspace():                                 # Checking if the current line is space  
            paragraphspace += 1                              # Increase paragraphspace (precedent line was space variable) +1
            continue
        else:
            spacechecker += 1                                # Any other case increase spacechecker +1    
            
            
        if spacechecker % 2 == 1:                                           # Check if spacechecker is odd
        
            for i in range(len(words)):                                     # If yes scan the words in normal order
            
                if words[i].strip(",.!?:;-") in gr_en != "[unavailable]":                      # If words[i] without any special char is in dictionary
                    currword = words[i]                                                        # If yes, we will call it "currword"
                    foundwords.append(currword)                                                # Add currword to the foundwords list    
                    wordcount += 1                                                             # Increase wordcount +1 
                    
                elif (words[i].strip(",.!?:;-") in gr_en == "[unavailable]" and wordcount >= k) or (currword not in gr_en and wordcount >= k):     #Elif check if it's not in dictionary but wordcount has gone over k
                     string = " ".join(foundwords)                                      # We will put the foundwords list in a string
                     completed_sequences.append(string)                                 # And add this string to the list of strings of completed_sequences
                     completed_paragraphs.append(paragraph)                             # Then add the paragraph of that string to the list of completed_paragraphs
                     result = list(zip(completed_sequences, completed_paragraphs))      # This the output format required, a tuple with the string and the paragraph of that string
                     wordcount = 0
                     
                     foundwords.clear()                                                 # Clearing the foundwords list
                   
                else:                                                     # If none of the above happened (word is not in dictionary and wordcounter still isn't >= k)
                    wordcount = 0                                         # Reset wordcount to 0  
                    foundwords.clear()                                    # Clear foundwords list      
                    continue                                              # Do nothing and cycle again 
                    
                    
        else:                                                             # The case of spacechecker being not odd,
            words = words[::-1]                                           # Reverse the word order
            
            for i in range(len(words)):                                        # Scanning the row of words
                currword = words[i][::-1]                                      # Currword in this case will be reversed since the words in even lines are written in reverse.
                if currword.strip(",.!?:;-") in gr_en != "[unavailable]":      # If currword without any special char is in dictionary
                    foundwords.append(currword)                                # Append it to the foundwords list 
                    wordcount += 1                                             # Increase wordcount +1     
                    
                elif (currword.strip(",.!?:;-") in gr_en == "[unavailable]" and wordcount >= k) or (currword.strip(",.!?:;-") not in gr_en and wordcount >= k):     #Elif check if it's not in dictionary but wordcount has gone over k
                     string = " ".join(foundwords)                                  # Add the words that has been found to the string  
                     completed_sequences.append(string)                             # Append the string to completed_sequences list      
                     completed_paragraphs.append(paragraph)                         # Append the paragraph of the strings to the completed_paragraphs list  
                     result = list(zip(completed_sequences, completed_paragraphs))  # Adding to the result the tuple combination of strings and corresponding paragraphs
                     wordcount = 0                                                  # Reset wordcount
                     
                     foundwords.clear()                                             # Clear foundwords list
                    
                else:                                                     # In case none of above happened     
                    wordcount = 0                                         # Reset wordcount to 0  
                    foundwords.clear()                                    # Clear foundwords list  
                    continue                                              # Do nothing and cycle again
```

Comment: May you post some code of yours?

Comment: @horcrux in case you're wondering why all the stuff regarding checking if line is odd or even that is because the text in ancient greek is written 1 line normal and 1 line in reverse (words must be reversed and their order too)

Comment: I've finished making comments to the code, now should be easier to read: 
https://pastebin.com/7eQEN5PG

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably take the following approach to solving this:

1. Try to collapse down the 2 word dictionaries into one (`ancient_italian` below), removing English from the equation. For example, if ancient->English has `{"canus": ["dog","puppy", "wolf"]}` and English->Italian has `{"dog":"cane"}` then you can create a new dictionary `{"canus": "cane"}`. (Of course if the English->Italian dict has all 3 English words, you need to either pick one, or display something like `cane|cucciolo|lupo` in the output).
2. Come up with a regular expression that can distinguish between words, and the separators (punctuation), and output them in order into a list (`word_list` below). I.e something like `['ecce', '!',  ' ', 'magnus', ' ',  'canus', ' ', 'esurit', '.']`
3. Step through this list, generating a new list. Something like:

```
translation = []
    for item in word_list:
      if item.isalpha():
        # It's a word - translate it and add to the list
        translation.append(ancient_italian[item])
      else:
        # It's a separator - add to the list as-is
        translaton.append(item)
```

4. Finally join the list back together: `''.join(translation)`

Comment: First of all thanks for trying to help me! 
1) As far as i understood every single english translation have one in Italian except for those words who are [unavailable] in the ancient greek - english dictionary (but they don't even matter).
What could be an efficient code to merge each value of GR_EN with the corresponding EN_IT dictionary?
2) This doesn't look a bad idea but i'm quite bad at managing strings, what could be a method to split words and punctuation? .split() method is useful in this case?
3) This doesn't put the word and the punctuation at different index of the list?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reply to your comment on the answer by match, but this may help:

For one, its not the most elegant approach but should work:

```
GR_IT = {}
for greek,eng in GR_EN.items():
    for word in eng:
        try:
            GR_IT[greek] = EN_IT[word]
        except:
            pass
```

If theres no translation for a word it will be ignored though.

To get a list of words and punctuation split try this:

```
def repl_punc(s):
    punct = ['.',',',':',';','?','!']
    for p in punct:
        s=s.replace(p,' '+p+' ')
    return s
repl_punc(s).split()
```

Comment: The dictionary works however looks like it takes only 1 translation in Italian for each word in greek. I need instead to take all the possible translations from the tuple in gr_en to make it 100% accurate.
Regarding the function looks like it's working great, this combined with a few controls will make the checking of existing words easier, thanks very much!

Comment: Try adding something like `translations = []` after the start of the first for loop then in the try block change it to `translations.append(EN_IT[word]); GR_IT[greek] = translations`. If that doesn't work can you provide a snippet of the translation dictionaries? Make sure to upvote if this has been useful too!

Comment: Looks like it worked but i don't understand why from the console variable it says 4375 elements for the GR_EN and 4084 elements for EN_IT when they're supposed to have the exact same amount. Now it's time to figure out an algorythm to make this whole thing work.
Anyway thank you very much! Got my upvote!

Comment: Ok nevermind, i just realized that this worked better than what i was expecting: all the words that are "Unavailable" so aren't in the EN_IT dict simply didn't go there so it's a clean list with only words that i have actual translation. Looks it's perfect

Comment: Glad to help! :)